# How to disable dropdown if no option selected on page load using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, dropdown

I have table with many dropdowns in it. I want to disable the dropdown if any option isn't selected on form load.

I tried this and it disable all dropdowns.

```
jQuery("Select.form-component").prop("disabled",true);
```

I want to disable only empty value dropdowns on form load using jquery

Comment: Can you show us some of the drop downs? It's probably because you are using a class name as the item to disable this on causing it to disable any element that has this class. Also, unless I'm missing something, I don't see any logic to check the select values that you are editing..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
$('select.form-component[value=""]').prop("disabled",true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
$('#dropDownId').attr('disabled', true);
```

or Javascript

```
document.getElementById("mySelect").disabled=true;
```